# Does Quick Charge have an effect on battery lifespan?

Tags: batteries, charging, cellphone, android

When charging my phone (a [Samsung Galaxy Note 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_4) using a 3,220mAh lithium-ion battery) I have the option of charging it with with a standard charger or a [Quick Charge 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge) charger. Quick Charge is a:

> proprietary technology which allows for the charging of battery
>   powered devices, primarily mobile phones, at levels above and beyond
>   the typical 5 volts and 2 amps which most USB standards allow for. [[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge#Details)]

Some technical details can also be found on the same Wikipedia page linked to above. My understanding is that in addition to higher voltage / amps, Quick Charge also uses a more sophisticated algorithm to provide variations of charging speeds at various %s of battery capacity to optimise the overall speed.

Using the Quick Charge offers a noticeable improvement to charging speed. However there are often situations where charging speed is irrelevant (e.g. at night).

My question is whether or not there is any difference in battery wear and lifespan between a standard charge and a Quick Charge. If there is a difference, then in situations where speed is irrelevant, it makes more sense to prioritise battery wear.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to give a general answer for all QC enabled devices.

It depends entirely on the implementation. Battery chemistry, configuration of charging circuitry, etc.

You have to ask the manufacturer or RTFM. Then you have to decide whether you want to trust their answer.